# Accessing PostGIS layers as non-data owner via QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I'm trying to create a database user (postgres) to access PostGIS data via QGIS.

I've applied the following commands:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO ene;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to ene;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "raiateaBD" TO ene;
```

The access tab for this database looks like this:
[image]

However, when creating a connection for this user in QGIS, the tables are not available.

[image]

Logging in as postgres user, the tables are visible and available to be loaded:
[image]

Furthermore, a project previously created with data loaded by postgres user (data owner) provokes the handle bad layers window when logged in as ene user.

[image]

The QGIS log has this error for each of the layers that are in the database:
[image]

I added the following, and the user 'ene' still does not have access:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.spatial_ref_sys TO ene;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.geography_columns TO ene;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.geometry_columns TO ene;
```

**BREAKTHROUGH**

Layer is accessible if I call:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public."table_name" TO ene;
```

However, I'd like to not calling it one by one, but the following command is not doing it:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ene;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're providing some stratospheric permissions when something more *plain vanilla* would suffice .  I loathe `public` as a security breach in waiting, but a `GRANT usage ON SCHEMA public TO username` combined with a `GRANT select ON tablename TO username` as the table owner ought to get you by.

Comment: can you double check that that user also has SELECT privileges to the public.geography_columns, public.geometry_columns and public.spatial_ref_sys tables? Assuming they are in the public schema. And at a minimum, usually only need to grant CONNECT privilege on the database, USAGE on the SCHEMA, and SELECT on the tables in question.

Comment: @SaultDon It appears as if they don't (ACL value doesn't show the extra user). This must be my problem...

Comment: @Vince So GRANT select ON tablename TO username; will work differently from what I've done with GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to ene;?

Comment: Sorry, no idea whatsoever.  I would never use either the `public` schema or the `ALL TABLES` construct.

Comment: Good computer security is based on the model of *least privileges necessary*.  Best practice involves roles (create role, grant SELECT to the role, grant the role to the user). So your question is marred by intent to avoid granting access on a table-by-table basis when that is in fact what you should do (albeit to the roles necessary to the security model, whereupon you can then grant the roles individually to logins).